# LDAP Authentication - Spring Security - LdapAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I'm struggling to have LDAP security configuration working with xml configuration.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean               with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested     exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider sgcbmw.security.SecurityConfig.ldapAuthenticationProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

My security configuration:

```
<bean id="contextSource"class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap:/ldapserver"/>
        <property name="userDn" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="pass"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
          class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
                <property name="userSearch">
                <bean id="userSearch"
                      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value=""/>
                    <constructor-arg index="1" value="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))"/>
                    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list><value>uid={0},ou=people</value></list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
                <constructor-arg value="ou=groups"/>
                <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="memberOf"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Configuration Adapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}
}
```

Shouldn't inject the LdapAuthenticationProvider this way?

Comment: is your context parsed at all?

Comment: What you mean by parsed? In web,xml I have the following code:  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: Try this, might help :injecting using setter of ldapAuthenticationProvider, create a setter of ldapAuthenticationProvider in SecurityConfig class ,remove @Autowired annotation.

Comment: Ricardo, are you sure your security xml config is parsed and LdapAuthenticationProvider is instantiated by Spring? To make sure, set breakpoints to all constructors in the LdapAuthenticationProvider class and run the project in debug mode. Is any breakpoint reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved my problem:

I've created one context xml configuration just for security and added the following to web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml classpath:spring/spring-security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And finally I let the beans configuration on my spring-security-config.xml and Autowire them on my class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Removed this from the xml:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: How can i instantiate object of LdapAuthenticationProvider without config.xml, rather java code ?